# quill : keep span id and class?

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

I am trying to customize Quill in such a way that I change the id and class of some spans included in the text (for example set a text with a given background color and give the created span a specific id and class).
I know that quill will "renormalize" the html code. When I move the selected text or copy-paste it, some characteristics are kept, but not the id and specific class. Is it possible in some way to make quill keep just the id and the class of the spans or divs it moves ? I don't want to add crazy html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in the latest version of Quill, but will be once [Custom Formats](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/milestones/Customizable%20Formats) is added in an upcoming release.